# How to cast list<object> to list<MyType> in java?

Tags: java, object, types, casting

PFB the code where i am trying to type cast `list<object>` to `list<MyType>` in java,

```
List<CoOffer> couponOffList = (List<CoOffer>)cioffers.getContent();
```

This `getContent()` returns `list<object>`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CiOffers")
public class CiOffers{

    @XmlElementRef(name = "CouponOffer", namespace = "http://www.ebi.com/webservices/", type = CouponOffer.class)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Object> content;
```

Now I have my java class `CoOffer`.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CoOffer implements Serializable{

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3155316759617764263L;
    private String cooffName;

    public String getCooffName() {
        return cooffName;
    }
    public void setCooffName(String cooffName) {
        cooffName= cooffName;
    }


}
```

How to cast list to list in java?

Comment: You can't cast it directly. Why are you having a `List<Object>` in the first place, rather than `List<CoOffer>`?

Comment: wat issue u face at List<CoOffer> couponOffList = (List<CoOffer>)cioffers.getContent(); ??

Comment: Why don't you just customize JAXB bindings to have `List<CoOffer>` instead `List<Object>`?

Comment: @NiksTyagi cannot cast error ...

Answer (score 1):

The property is annotated `@XmlMixed` which means it represents mixed content, so the cast you're asking about isn't guaranteed to be safe - the list may contain a mixture of `CouponOffer` objects (representing the elements) and `java.lang.String` objects (representing the mixed content text nodes in between elements).

Answer (score 0):

You ***cannot*** cast it directly in a *type-safe* manner. Yes you can perform an unchecked cast, but that is not a good idea.

Now a `List<Object>` can contain any type of object, and `List<MyType>` can only contain objects of type `MyType`. So *its not possible*.

Solution is to make JAXB generate `List<MyType>` than `List<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper method to cast return a new list.

```
public <T> List<T> castTo(List<Object> ol, Class<T> t) {
    List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : ol) {
        try {
            ret.add(t.cast(o));
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage()+" "+o);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And use it like that:

```
@Test
public void testCastTo() {
    Class<MyType> t = MyType.class;
    List<Object> ol = new ArrayList<>();
    ol.add(new MyType(1));
    ol.add("12");
    ol.add(new MyType(123));
    List<MyType> l = c.castTo(ol, t);

    assertEquals(2,l.size());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that returned object is `List<CoOffer>` you can cast it.
As;

```
(List<CoOffer>)(Object)cioffers.getContent();
```